# javascript find control id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkboxes generated with an auto ID

I am using the function below:

```
getAllSelectedFeeds = function() {
 var val = []; 
 $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
   val[i] = $(this).attr('id');
 });
 return val;
};
```

It checks if any checkboxes are checked but I **only** want it to run for those checkbox controls with "selectedTask" within their autogenerated id such as `id="ctl00_m_g_95e8bffc_8200_46ac_887c_98522e26803c_ctl01_ctl02_selectedTask`

Would this javascript work (using jquery selector) by selecting only those checkboxes checked within a div called 'feedSelector'?
//Get selected checkboxes IDs

```
getAllSelectedFeeds = function() {
 var val = []; 
 $('#feedSelector:input:checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
  val[i] = $(this).attr('id');
 });
 return val;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
getAllSelectedFeeds = function() {
 var val = []; 
 $('input:checkbox:checked[id*=selectedTask]').each(function(i) {
   val[i] = $(this).attr('id');
 });
 return val;
};
```

(if it always ends with "selectedTask" you can use $= instead of *=)

Although I'd really recommend avoiding doing it like this as it has to search every ID for that string, which is inefficient. Might want to add a class to the checkboxes so you can just query on that because it'll be a lot faster, especially if you start to get a lot of checkboxes:

```
getAllSelectedFeeds = function() {
 var val = []; 
 $('input.selectedTask:checked').each(function(i) {
   val[i] = $(this).attr('id');
 });
 return val;
};
```

Comment: Would this work if I used a div around the checkboxes called 'feedSelector'

$('#feedSelector:input:checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {

Comment: If you did that your syntax for the selector would be $('#feedSelector input:checkbox:checked'). But yes that would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
getAllSelectedFeeds = function() {
 var val = []; 
 $('input:checkbox:checked[id*=selectedTask]').each(function(i) {
   val[i] = $(this).attr('id');
 });
 return val;
};
```

With this you get every checked checkbox with an id that contains "selectedTask"